# Namespace not defined in F# ASP.NET MVC project in VS Code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, f#, nuget

I'm currently trying to make some progress in learning F# and web development, and to that end I've used Yeoman to generate a F# ASP.NET project to start with ([generator](https://github.com/omnisharp/generator-aspnet#readme)).

I've used Bower to install the dependencies, and the project both builds and runs with no issues, in both VS Code and just using `dotnet run`. However, navigating to the Startup.fs, it claims these namespaces opened aren't defined:

```
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
open Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
open Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
```

In the .fsproj file, the following packages are included, and I have run `dotnet restore`:

```
<PackageReference Include="FSharp.NET.Sdk" Version="1.0.0-beta-*" PrivateAssets="All"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.0.3"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.0.2"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.0.2"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.FSharp.Core.netcore" Version="1.0.0-alpha-161023"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.0.1"/>
```

To my mind, those lines should include at least some of the relevant NuGet packages for the namespace above. I would like to know how to let VS Code see that these namespaces are defined in the packages, and what's currently wrong. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried reloading the VSCode window?

Comment: I have, multiple times. Reopening the file doesn't solve the issue I'm afraid

Comment: "reopening the file"? I meant reload the whole vscode.

Comment: Ah, I meant that I'd both reloaded the whole VSCode, and also closed/reopened the folder.

Comment: I haven't used F# with core however I noticed that you have as a reference <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.FSharp.Core.netcore" Version="1.0.0-alpha-161023"/>. I have a .net core 2 preview installed and generating new web project via dotnet command generated reference to  <PackageReference Include="FSharp.Core" Version="4.1.*" /> and <PackageReference Include="FSharp.NET.Sdk" Version="1.0.*" PrivateAssets="All" /> which has not issues in VS Code

Comment: Here be dragons. Are you wedded to ASP.NET? For web stuff you should check out [Fable](http://fable.io/).

Comment: @AlexanderM Package versions seemed to be the issue! Turned out to be the FSharp.NET.Sdk version. Updating it to the latest version (currently 1.0.5, so 1.0.* works) fixed it. Could you add yours as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @s952163 I'm not wedded to ASP.NET, but am trying to use technologies I'm less familiar with, F# being one of them. As an aside, I'm trying to use ASP.NET Core, and from what I hear things have changed some? Fable looks quite interesting on the side of games things, but the idea I'm aiming at will probably require a full stack. Input is welcomed though, I'm completely new to F# web development.

Comment: @OctarineSorcerer there is a #web (and #dotnetcore) channel on the [Fsharp Slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per comments under the question moving my comment to the answer:

I haven't used F# with core however I noticed that you have a reference

```
<PackageReference Include="FSharp.NET.Sdk" Version="1.0.0-beta-*" PrivateAssets="All"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.FSharp.Core.netcore" Version="1.0.0-alpha-161023"/>.
```

I have a .net core 2 preview installed and generating new web project via dotnet command generated reference to

```
<PackageReference Include="FSharp.Core" Version="4.1.*" /> 
<PackageReference Include="FSharp.NET.Sdk" Version="1.0.*" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

which has not issues in VS Code